# multiple IF on the same column

Tags: google-bigquery

A stupid question:

I have to group in the same column different if statements. How can I do?

if(string='AAA','A','other'), if(string='BBB','B','other') AS COLUMN 1

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

use case statement

```
Select
Case 
When string="AAA" then "A_String"
When string="BBB" then "B_String"
When String in ("CCC","DDD") then "C_OR_D_String"
Else "Unknow_String"
End AS String_Class
From My_Table
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the `Simulating a Pivot Table` section from the [Query Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#otherfunctions)

Use conditional statements to organize the results of a subselect query into rows and columns. In the example below, results from a search for most revised Wikipedia articles that start with the value 'Google' are organized into columns where the revision counts are displayed if they meet various criterea.

```
SELECT
  page_title,
  /* Populate these columns as True or False, */
  /*  depending on the condition */
  IF (page_title CONTAINS 'search', 
      INTEGER(total), 0) AS search,
  IF (page_title CONTAINS 'Earth' OR 
      page_title CONTAINS 'Maps', INTEGER(total), 0) AS geo,
FROM
  /* Subselect to return top revised Wikipedia articles */
  /* containing 'Google', followed by additional text. */
  (SELECT
    TOP (title, 5) as page_title,
    COUNT (*) as total
   FROM
     [publicdata:samples.wikipedia]
   WHERE
     REGEXP_MATCH (title, r'^Google.+') AND wp_namespace = 0
  );
```

Returns:

```
+---------------+--------+------+
|  page_title   | search | geo  |
+---------------+--------+------+
| Google search |   4261 |    0 |
| Google Earth  |      0 | 3874 |
| Google Chrome |      0 |    0 |
| Google Maps   |      0 | 2617 |
| Google bomb   |      0 |    0 |
+---------------+--------+------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a stupid question... this happens more often as you expect when cleaning data in BQ.

Even tho the other answers are a good workaround for your question if you want to write your query with If Statements, this will be the way to do it:

```
IF(string = 'AAA','A',(IF(string = 'BBB','B,'other'))) as COLUMN,
```

You are in this case just nesting the IF statements, and it's gonna work as long as your 'other' value will be the same for both IF statements when the condition is not valid.